# How to write a function to pass parameter and get corresponding database value

Tags: java, database, web-services

```
public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(Connection connection) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = new ArrayList<FeedObjects>();
        try
        {
            //String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website ORDER BY id DESC");
            //ps.setString(1,uname);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                FeedObjects feedObject = new FeedObjects();
                feedObject.SetId(rs.getInt("id"));
                feedObject.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                feedObject.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                feedObject.setUrl(rs.getString("url"));
                feedData.add(feedObject);
            }
            return feedData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

This is my code from which i am able to display all data from  employee table. I want write function so that if i pass id then i will get corresponding  column values.

E.g if we input id =1 then it should display only id one emp_name .

please help me and modified me the given function so that i can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Then add  a [`WHERE clause`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29)

```
SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website where id= "+userId+"
```

That returns a record with that particular `Id` ,assuming Id is unique.

Looks like

```
public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetUserFeed(Connection connection, long userId) 
                                                            throws Exception
```

So now your function needs to receive `userId` as a  argument.

**Note:** Do not mix two methods. Write a separate method to receive **user id** and an common method to receive all feeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(Connection connection) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = new ArrayList<FeedObjects>();
        try
        {
            //String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website where id = "<PASS ID HERE>" ORDER BY id DESC");
            //ps.setString(1,uname);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                FeedObjects feedObject = new FeedObjects();
                feedObject.SetId(rs.getInt("id"));
                feedObject.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                feedObject.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                feedObject.setUrl(rs.getString("url"));
                feedData.add(feedObject);
            }
            return feedData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

try this

Comment: I have write web service plz Provide me complete. Using Query String http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds  this my URL from which i am Getting value

Comment: It's generally thought not to be very helpful to post code only answers

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(Connection connection,int id) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = new ArrayList<FeedObjects>();
    try
    {
        //String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website where id=? ORDER BY id DESC");
        ps.setInt(1,id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            FeedObjects feedObject = new FeedObjects();
            feedObject.SetId(rs.getInt("id"));
            feedObject.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            feedObject.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            feedObject.setUrl(rs.getString("url"));
            feedData.add(feedObject);
        }
        return feedData;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` to your SQL statement...

The correct method when using `PreparedStatement` is to inject values rather than append them like so

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website ORDER BY id DESC WHERE id=?");
ps.setInt(1, id); //you only have 1 '?' so the index is 1, if you had another it would be 2, etc
```

You will of course need to pass your id into the function however.

The reason you are better injecting into the `PreparedStatement` rather than appending like so

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website ORDER BY id DESC WHERE id="+id);
```

is because then you are catching possible SQL injection attacks.  Not something you probably have to worry about at this point but it's good practice.

Comment: Actually i am writing web service i have to pass value using Query String

Comment: Then get it from there `int id = request.getParameter("id");`

Comment: That i did alredy [http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html ] I have write this web service currently i am fetching all data pass id in Query string of URl and corresponding title value i should get

Comment: So what is the problem you are having now?

Comment: See currently am getting all value from database table . i want if we pass id value then i should get corresponding title value .eg if we select 3  this valur should return :"title":"Java MySQL Insert Record using Jquery.",
"description":"Description Text",
"url":"http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/java-mysql-insert-record-using-jquery.html"

Comment: Oh, you only want the title returned? Then change your SQL to only ask for title 
`SELECT title FROM website WHERE id=?`

Comment: can u please give me changes in this classes http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html plz so that i can pass value id and get

Comment: I gave you enough information to do what you ask.  I can't simply write the program for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(Connection connection, int id) throws Exception {
    //...
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website where id = ?");
    ps.setInt(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    //...
}
```

Comment: public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds()throws Exception {
  ArrayList<FeedObjects> feeds = null;
  try {
       Database database= new Database();
       Connection connection = database.Get_Connection();
    Project project= new Project();
    feeds=project.GetFeeds(connection,id);
  
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw e;
  }
  return feeds;
 }  here What i will change

Comment: You need to pass the id to search for. It is not defined in the snippet you have provided.

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html  This Example i did for web service i have to write web service so that i can pass id value in that meothod using QUerystring and get the  corresponding value plz help me